# User id в telegram Python api

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Доброе время суток!
Вот код и почему-то не хочет выдавать или добавили юзер айди.

```
users_id = []
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def begin(message):
    for id in users_id:
        if id != message.from_user.id :
            users_id.append(message.from_user.id)
            print(users_id)
```

Comment: поскольку до захода в функцию список пустой, у вас id пробегает циклом по пустому списку, то есть нет ни единой итерации. Сделайте сначала проверку на пустоту списка, если пустой то добавьте элемент. А если не пустой, то циклом сравнивайте id с message.from_user.id

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте следующее:

```
if message.from_user.id not in users:
    users.append(message.from_user.id)
```